# Deleting specific ChartObjects by Name Property Excel VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I have an excel worksheet with two chart objects (pie chart and line graph). I have separate buttons to generate each graph and I want to delete the according pre-existing graph each time the generation button is pressed. Right now, I am attempting to access the Name property of the chart object to determine if the chart needs to be deleted. The deletion code looks like this:

```
For i = 1 To ActiveSheet.ChartObjects.Count
    If ActiveSheet.ChartObjects(i).Chart.Name = "Genre" Then
        ActiveSheet.ChartObjects("Genre").Delete
    End If
Next i
```

Here is the code that generates the piechart:

```
Range("A2:B16").Select
ActiveSheet.Shapes.AddChart.Select
ActiveChart.ChartType = xlPie 'Exploded
ActiveChart.SetElement (msoElementChartTitleAboveChart)
ActiveChart.ChartTitle.Text = "Genre Breakdown"
ActiveChart.Parent.Name = "Genre"
Dim ChartSize As ChartObject
Set ChartSizing = Worksheets("Graphs and Stats").ChartObjects("Genre")
With ChartSizing
    .Top = Range("D2").Top
    .Width = Range("D2:H23").Width
    .Height = Range("D2:H23").Height
    .Left = Range("D2").Left
End With
```

Currently, the If-statement in the deletion for loop never resolves as true and I don't understand why. What is wrong with that line and/or is there better logic I could be using to check for pre-existing charts? I would prefer not use

```
ActiveSheet.ChartObjects.Delete
```

if I can avoid it to keep the generation buttons separate from each other.

**EDIT:** Corrected code (where worksheet name is "Graphs and Stats") using Dammer15's solution:

```
For i = 1 To ActiveSheet.ChartObjects.Count
    If ActiveSheet.ChartObjects(i).Chart.Name = "Graphs and Stats Genre" Then
        ActiveSheet.ChartObjects("Genre").Delete
    End If
Next i

Set Rng = ActiveSheet.Range("A2:B16")
Set GenreChart = ActiveSheet.Shapes.AddChart
GenreChart.Name = "Genre"
With GenreChart.Chart
    .SetSourceData Source:=Rng
    .ChartType = xlPie
    .SetElement (msoElementChartTitleAboveChart)
    .ChartTitle.Text = "Genre Breakdown"
End With
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You never get the correct Chart Name. Use the sheets and indexing you need but here's the general idea. You must remove the Sheet name from the accessed property.

```
'List of Chart Objects
Dim ChartList As ChartObjects

'The square that holds the chart
Dim MyChartFrame As ChartObject
Dim ChartToDelete As ChartObject

'The Physical chart with data
Dim MyChart As Chart

'Accessing the Objects
Set ChartList = Sheet1.ChartObjects
Set MyChartFrame = Sheet1.ChartObjects(1)
Set MyChart = MyChartFrame.Chart

Dim ChartName As String

'Remove SheetName from ChartName!!!!
ChartName = MyChart.Name

'Deleting Chart
Set ChartToDelete = Sheet1.ChartObjects(ChartName)
ChartToDelete.Delete
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks! I didn't realize that the sheet name was being appended to the name of the chart property when accessed. I revised my code and everything is working properly.